# Yup - validate required name - split value into array of string - with min-max length of values

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I'm using react hook form with yup .I need to validate first and last name in one field is fullName.
so I need to split the value with (" ")  , with min and max length of each value(first and last name)

what I've tried

```
const registerSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  fullName:Yup.string()
  .test({message: () => 'must be full name!',
  test(value:any) {
    const nameArr = value.split(" ");
    return nameArr.length >= 2;
  }
  }),
```

this is valid when the second value empty .
`firstName + (" ")  this valid and i want lastName with specific length`

how to set **min/max of length of both**( first and last name ) and customize error message for that?